# How to use flexbox to place a button on to the right side of InputSelect?

Tags: c#, css, .net, flexbox, blazor

I'm trying to place a button on the right of a dropdown however everything I try, it seems to place the button above the dropdown. I'd need it next to 'Select Organisation' in the below picture.

[image]

I've got the below code which includes the InputSelect and the button in question

```
 <div class="form-group row mb-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <div class="form-floating">
            <InputSelect id="Organisation" class="form-select" @bind-Value="Meeting.OrganisationId">
                <option value="0">Select Organisation:</option>
                @foreach (var org in Organisations)
                {
                    <option value="@org.Id">@org.Name</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-end"><span class="oi oi-plus"></span></button>
            <label for="Organisation">Organisation</label>
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Meeting.OrganisationId)" />
    </div>
```

I've also tried `float-end` and `pull-left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added flex-direction to the parent of the button and the inputselect, this should work for you.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="form-group row mb-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <div class="form-floating container">
            <InputSelect id="Organisation" class="form-select" @bind-Value="Meeting.OrganisationId">
                <option value="0">Select Organisation:</option>
                @foreach (var org in Organisations)
                {
                    <option value="@org.Id">@org.Name</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-end"><span class="oi oi-plus">Button</span></button>
            <label for="Organisation">Organisation</label>
        </div>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Meeting.OrganisationId)" />
    </div>
```